# Epoch to timeStamp without the timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, epoch, date-conversion

I input the epoch 1635759368000 and want to convert to regular timestamp

`select to_timestamp(1635759368000/1000)`

Gives me an output of

`2021-11-01 05:36:08.000 -0400`

But I just want

`2021-11-01 05:36:08.000`

How would I do this?

Comment: Why you want a wrong time? Epoch 1635759368 secs = 2021-11-01 09:36:08 . It is assumed to be a GMT time as an epoch time value is not associated with any time zone.  and it is exactly 2021-11-01 05:36:08 -0400 .

Comment: From here [Datetime functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html): `to_timestamp ( double precision ) → timestamp with time zone`. It would be a good idea to leave the offset in so have an anchored point in time. If you want to lose that then: `select to_timestamp(1635759368000/1000)::timestamp;`